C# Serilog log the console output to file for each application execution (without loosing the console output) [Console application]
I'm developping a console application using .NET.
This application writes a lot in the console and there is some user interaction that I would like to log into a file each time the application is ran using Serilog.
I don't want to redirect the whole console output into a log file and loose the console output, I want both.
I didn't find how to tell to Serilog to log the console output to a file (and keep the console output) ...

Why not add a File sink along with the Console sink? You can limit each sink to record specific levels or sources too

There's no reason to redirect the console output. Serilog allows writing to multiple sinks, including files, eg :
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.File("log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();

It's possible to filter the messages written to each sink. This way, one can write all logs to a log.txt file and warnings and errors to errors.txt, while still sending everything to the console :
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.File("log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .WriteTo.File("errors.txt",LogEventLevel.Warning, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();

You can filter what gets logged to each sink too, and log eg only events created from specific sources :
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc           
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly( Matching.FromSource<MyClass>())
        .WriteTo.File("myclasslog.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    )
    ...
    .CreateLogger();


There is a Serilog extension that allows to use expressions for filtering logs according to specific usecases.
To address your specific usecase a filter that only applied to the user interactions would be required. Assuming that you have a specific file/namespace that is responsible for the user actions a Serilog configuration could look like this:
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
        {
            "Name": "File",
            "Args": {
                "path": "./default.log"
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "Async",
            "Args": {
                "configure": [
                    {
                        "Name": "Console"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "Name": "Logger",
            "Args": {
                "configureLogger": {
                    "WriteTo": [
                        {
                            "Name": "File",
                            "Args": {
                                "path": "./userEvent.log"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "Filter": [
                        {
                            "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                            "Args": {
                                "expression": "StartsWith(SourceContext, 'LoggingExample.UserEvent')"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ]
}

The write to sections with name File and Async will continue to log as you would expect, this includes the user events.
The relevant section is that called Logger.
Here a logger that writes to a file is specified with a filter that only logs events that stem from the namespace LoggingExample.UserEvent. This would have to be changed to the respective namespace of where your logic for user interactions resides.
NOTE: This will only work when using the Nuget package referenced above
